# Making Only Specific Functions and Variables Available in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, constants

I want to make a programming environment. I will explain it with an example.

One programmer will write that code;

```
<html>
 <head>
  <?php definedMetaTags(); ?>
 </head>
</body>
```

Programmer will save this file and then upload to my system. That file will be executed at server side and then they system will turn generated code back.

That definedMetaTags() function will be already written in the system.

An example of Compiler.php:

```
<?php
 require_once("definitionsForProgrammer.php");
 include("uploadedfile.php");
?>
```

My question is that I want to allow that uploadedfile.php only what functions I want. Else, maybe that programmer writes some codes what I want him/her to do. (Deleting files, mysql connection, etc.)

Is there any way to allow a code only specific functions, variables, constans?

Comment: Have you considered XMLRPC or SOAP for this purpose?

Comment: I actually want the code to be sent to me (to server) firstly. I dont want user to send a request and take it's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aiming for security and you want to let them to write functions, then the short answer is: no.

Essentially you're asking for a PHP sandbox which will let you constrain what code can be executed.  PHP would have to support this at a fundamental level for it to work.  For example, supposing you took the approach of saying "I only allow the user to write a function named 'foo'".  Inside that function, though the user can do all kinds of bad things like making system calls, downloading other code and executing it, etc.  In order to prevent this you'd need to implement checks at a much lower level in the system.

If you're willing to restrict the scope only to variable definitions then yes you can do it.  You can use token_get_all() and token_name() to examine the file to make sure that it doesn't have any code that you don't want in it.  For example:

```
foreach (token_get_all(file_get_contents("uploadedfile.php")) as $token) {
  if (is_array($token)) {
    echo token_name($token[0]), " ";
  } else {
    echo $token;
  }
}
```

If you don't like any tokens you see, don't include the file.  You could theoretically guard against bad functions this way as well, but it'll require a fair amount of effort to properly parse the file and make sure that they're not doing something bad.

references:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-name.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: Would that guard against variable variables too?

Comment: If you are asking me than yes, I also want that security for variables also. Because you know there lots of information in $_SERVER, and other variables which I dont remember now.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to allow a user to insert placeholders that will be replaced by some PHP function execution, then there's no need to treat the uploaded file as PHP code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  {[definedMetaTags]}
 </head>
</body>
```

Then Compiler.php would look like this:

```
<?php
 require_once("definitionsForProgrammer.php");

 $macros = array();
 $macros['definedMetaTags'] = definedMetaTags();

 $output = file_get_contents("uploadedfile.php");
 foreach($macros as $macro=>$value) $output = str_replace("{[$macro]}", $value, $output);

 echo $output;
?>
```

The `definedMetaTags()` function would need to be reworked so that it returns the tags as a string instead of printing them directly to output.

This method would allow you to define any number of macros without exposing yourself to all the security risks the others here have mentioned.

Comment: Schwartzie, your way is good but the problem is I will use this thing for lots of programming languages. C++, Java, Javascript, Html, Python, etc. So, str_replace sometimes may work wrong for different languages. Yes HTML doesn't use {[...]} style normally, but we may can see that style coding in other languages. That's the problem actually.

Comment: Does your application have a name?  Just use that--or some other reasonably distinct string--as a prefix to the macro: `{[TolgaApp_definedMetaTags]}`.  While this won't avoid collisions with an arbitrary language's syntax, it will certainly avoid the unintentional ones and puts only a reasonable constraint on the users.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if i'm understanding your question correctly. If you include("uploadedfile.php"); you will acquire **everything** in it.

What you could do is break your code up into related sections (whether it be via classes or just function definitions in a file) then only include the file/class that you want.

(let me know if that's not what your asking)

Comment: I will combine your thought (class) and bharat's way. So, I will only allow user to use the variables and functions of that class. I will let you know if it works well.